# Get HTTP Post Data from ServletRequest while debugging with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, http, servlets

How I can get HTTP Post Data from ServletRequest while debugging with Eclipse?

I want to check a form data values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "Debug on the server". In order to do this, put a breakpoint at the beginnning of your `servlet` `doPost` method. Next, when the server works, start your web browser, and send a POST-request to the local machine. A pop-up window should appear, prompting you to debug step by step. In the right window in Eclipse you should see the list of all variables, and their values. Find your `ServletRequest`, and examine its contents.

Comment: Find your ServletRequest, and examine its contents. That is the point what I want to learn. Which content?

Comment: there should be key-value pairs, which are Strings, and represent Post request data.